# Localize arbitrary iOS app resources

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect, bundle, app-thinning

I'd like to bundle an arbitrary, localization-specific file along with each app release, so that it's on-device for users who first open the app without an internet connection. Obviously, bundling the 100+ regions we support would be prohibitive because of the size of the files.

In my use case this is a region-specific catalogue, but there are obviously others.

Is this possible? I understand the process of bundling localized string files, for language support, but this is different.